# How can I get i2cget to read a word?

Tags: i2c

i2cget doesn't like the w mode

Cannot get i2cget to read a word. Will not accept mode w.

```
root@spring:~#

root@spring:~# i2cget -V  
i2cget version 3.1.2

root@spring:~# i2cget -y 2 0x28  
0x1b

root@spring:~# i2cget -y 2 0x28 w  
Error: Data address invalid!
Usage: i2cget [-f] [-y] I2CBUS CHIP-ADDRESS [DATA-ADDRESS [MODE]]
  I2CBUS is an integer or an I2C bus name
  ADDRESS is an integer (0x03 - 0x77)
  MODE is one of:
    b (read byte data, default)
    w (read word data)
    c (write byte/read byte)
    Append p for SMBus PEC

root@spring:~#
```

running Debian version 9.7 on a Beaglebone Green
reading a Honeywell pressure sensor:

> To read out a compensated pressure reading, the master generates a START condition and sends the sensor slave address followed by a read bit (shown in Figure 2). After the sensor generates an acknowledge, it will transmit up to 4 bytes of data – the first two bytes containing the compensated pressure output, and the second two bytes containing the optional compensated temperature output.
>   The master must acknowledge the receipt of each byte, and can terminate the communication by sending a Not Acknowledge (NACK) bit followed by a stop bit after receiving both bytes of data as show in Figure 2.

Ah the answer is that I failed to put in the data-address.

i2cget -y 2 0x28 0x28 w
yields
0xd517

Thanks to domen for setting me straight

Answer (score 1):

*Usage: i2cget [-f] [-y] I2CBUS CHIP-ADDRESS [DATA-ADDRESS [MODE]]*

Your example: `i2cget -y 2 0x28 w`

What's `DATA-ADDRESS` in your case?